# Mbunit tests are not loaded

Tags: unit-testing, mbunit, gallio

I am using Mbunit, and I have written the tests in Mbunit. However, when I am trying to run the tests, it gives me an error:

> No tests were run because the tests are not loaded or disabled.

Comment: what test runner are you using?

Comment: I will try to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more information such as what version of MbUnit do use and what test runner do use?

If you use version 2 than make sure that decorated your class with [TextFixture] attribute and the test method with [Test] one.

Comment: And ensure that your test fixture classes and your test methods are **public**.